# how to recover data for a specific app,

Tags: iphone

I just had a new ihone. I did my restore function and the only app that did not get back my data is killshot bravo.  does anyone know why.  I lost everything I had, guns money and gold in that game :((

Answer (score 2):

According to [this](https://hotheadgames.helpshift.com/a/kill-shot/?s=account-recovery&f=can-i-transfer-my-progress-to-another-device) article, it sounds as game progress is only saved when you sign in using a Facebook or Google account.   If you aren't signing in to the game that way, it will not save / backup your progress.

Also, according to [this](https://hotheadgames.helpshift.com/a/kill-shot/?s=account-recovery&f=i-have-a-problem-with-the-game-should-i-reinstall-the-game-on-my-device) article, the company offers no guarantee that game progress would be saved.   Sounds pretty shady to me.

Answer (score -1):

You can reinstall an application and restore its data as long as you backed up iPhone with iTunes on your computer. (If you try to delete an application that hasn’t been backed up to your computer, an alert appears.) To retrieve the application data, you must restore iPhone from a backup containing the data." But if it does not work for your case, maybe there's no other way to retrieve the game data...